# Bootstrap accordion not working with local source

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and have hosted it locally. When giving the extensions

```
<link href="../extensions/bootstrap-3.3.5/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../extensions/bootstrap-3.3.5/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

the accordion doesn't work instead gives `http://localhost:8085/header.php#collapseUsage` but when I use the links online

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

it works fine. I have checked and the path to file is correct, the CSS works fine too. Only the accordion doesn't work. Where have I gone wrong or what am I missing? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery file before the bootstrap file.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="../extensions/bootstrap-3.3.5/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../extensions/bootstrap-3.3.5/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

check for `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` file called location. is it live link as shown in this example? if yes then download it in your folder and call it from local path just like you call css file.

Comment: Aah yes! This link is there in my code..  Thanks for the help.. appreciate it :)